# SQL copy unique records between two equal databases in two separate databases

Tags: sql, select, insert, copy

Here is the thing: I have 2 databases ADatabaseCX and ADatabaseRH. Databases are the same. I have some records in both datatables. What I would like to do is insert entries from ADatabaseCX to ADatabaseRH, BUT only entries, that doesn't exist in ADatabaseRH - in RH there is incomplete data.

I tried with nested SQL, something like this:

```
    SELECT a.* 
    FROM ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes AS a
    LEFT JOIN ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes AS b ON (ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes.recipeId = ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes.recipeId)
    WHERE b.recipeId IS NULL
```

But it says

```
    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
    The multi-part identifier "ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes.recipeId" could not be bound.
    Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
    The multi-part identifier "ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes.recipeId" could not be bound.
```

Fist (first idea) I tried

```
    SELECT * FROM ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT recipeId FROM ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes)
```

But this returns me no records.

While copying I would also like to copy in a way that IDs would stay the same.

I am using MS SQL Server 2008.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are initializing an `ALIAS` on the database name but you have not used it in the `ON` clause, it should be

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes AS a
       LEFT JOIN ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes AS b 
          ON a.recipeId = b.recipeId
WHERE  b.recipeId IS NULL
```

database name and table name are not valid anymore after the initialization of an `ALIAS` on each of them that's why you are getting that error message.

Comment: Thanks! I marked your post as answer since you were the first one to answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this referencing `a.recipeId` and `b.recipeId`:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes AS a
LEFT JOIN ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes AS b ON a.recipeId = b.recipeId
WHERE b.recipeId IS NULL
```

Or this would also work using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes 
WHERE recipeId NOT IN (
    SELECT recipeId 
    FROM ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I could mark only one post as answer (since it is correct answer too) I will upvote your post. Thanks!

Comment: @CyberHawk -- no worries, glad we could help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that you have aliased the tables but then not used those aliases in the join.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM ADatabaseCX.dbo.Recipes AS a
    LEFT JOIN ADatabaseRH.dbo.Recipes AS b ON (a.recipeId = b.recipeId)
WHERE b.recipeId IS NULL
```

Edit: Couple of minutes late on this by the looks of it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I could mark only one post as answer I will upvote your post (since it is answer too). Thanks!